# Largest possible Supply an Ethereum token that can be created?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

What is the largest possible token supply an ERC-20 that can be created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `totalSupply` variable in ERC20 is an `uint256` type it can hold the largest value *2^256-1* whose value is 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935

Comment: If it answers your question completely, please mark it correct answer